# maintaining two different session same time in mvc

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, model-view-controller

I am using mvc concept normal bean class concept in which i have one jsp page here i am logged as different user and putting in search option other person detail and fetching from database so searching a person from database we have one function in our business class its getting executed and returning value on console also but m not able to fetch those value on jsp page and unable to print either its getting null or printing the existing user detail in which i have already logged in here is my code

first jsp page where we are getting input

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <%
 Employee emp1 = (Employee)session.getAttribute("emp1");
 session.setAttribute("emp1",emp1);
 %>
        <fieldset id="fieldhead">
        <legend>Check Employee Details</legend><BR>
        <table align=center cellspacing=1 cellpadding=3><form name ="form" method=post action="SearchEmployee">
            <center>
            <tr><Td>Enter keywords</td><TD><input name="data" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit"  value="SearchEmployee" />
           &nbsp;&nbsp;<button type=reset accesskey="R"><u>R</u>efresh</button></td></tr>
            </center>
        </table><BR>
        </fieldset>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

here is my servlet code where i am receiving values and calling function of business class

```
   @WebServlet(name = "SearchEmployee", urlPatterns = {"/SearchEmployee"})
    public class SearchEmployee extends HttpServlet {
    int z2;
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);    
     Employee emp1 = (Employee)session.getAttribute("emp1");
     emp1.setData(request.getParameter("data"));
     EmployeeBean eb = new EmployeeBean();
     List<Employee> search = eb.SearchEmployee(emp1);
     request.setAttribute("search", search);
     request.getRequestDispatcher("/SearchResult.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
  }

 @Override
 public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
 }
 }
```

here is my business class function which i am calling from servlet

```
  public List<Employee> SearchEmployee(Employee emp1) {
  Connection con = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  String p = emp1.getData();
  List<Employee> search = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  try {
      int count =0;
      con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
      stmt = con.createStatement();
      String Query = "SELECT * FROM empinfo WHERE empName ='"+p+"' or fathername ='"+p+"' or  mailid = '"+p+"' or contactnum = '"+p+"' ";
      System.out.println("Query is " +Query);
       rs= stmt.executeQuery(Query);
      while (rs.next())
        {
     count++; 
       emp1 = new Employee();
    int qw = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("empId"));
    String name = rs.getString("empName");
    System.out.println("name is " +name);
    System.out.println("qw is " +qw);
    emp1.setIid(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("empId")));
    emp1.setName(rs.getString("empName"));
    search.add(emp1);
    System.out.println("............" +search);
    emp1.setValid(true);
        } System.out.println("records retrieved from the DB: "+count);
  } catch (SQLException  ex) {

  } finally {
      try {
          if (stmt != null) {
              stmt.close();
          }
          if (con != null) {
              con.close();
          }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(EmployeeBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  }
  return search;
  }
```

here is my last jsp search result

```
<html>
 <body>
 <%
 Employee emp1=(Employee)session.getAttribute("emp1");
 session.setAttribute("emp1",emp1);
 %>
    <h5>${message}</h5>
        <div align="center">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="3" width ="500px" >
        <caption><h2>List of Employee for leave Request</h2></caption>
            <tr>
            <th>employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${search}" var="item">
           <tr>
           <td>${item.getIid()}</td>  
           <td><a href ="SearchEmployee?data=${item.getName()}">${item.getName()}</a></td>
          </tr>
          </c:forEach>  
       </table>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: please anyone help me here...

Comment: From your title _maintaining two different session same time in mvc_ sessions are for current users. explain your problem clearly

Comment: sir not for current users... my question is very simple i am logged in with one employee id and searching in search bar other employee detail by giving some keywords related to his detail which i have passed in my sql query... and returning his detail ... but i have setter and getter method in bean class which are common for all amployee so suppose... int n = emp1.getEmpid() is referring current employee .. but i have to fetch id of searched user also in jsp page

Comment: Try setting the values in the request instead of session

Comment: continue here... jsp page like... int z = emp1.getEmpId() so Empid is the method which will be same but here i should give like this emp2.getEmpId(); so it can hold other employee id so how to retrieve.. this

Comment: u meant? session.setAttribute("emp1",emp1) ...? i have tried it is returning logged in employee details plz sir help here..